# GStreamer Time Lapse Video: Out of sequence JPEG in first frame

Tags: ios, video, gstreamer, macos-high-sierra

Here's the code I'm using to create a time lapse video from a set of sequentially named JPEG files:

```
home="/home/pi/webcam"
log="$home/webcam.log"
file="$home/arch/test/kamvideo.mp4" ## name of video file to create
vpath="$home/arch/test/" ## path to video files
rmpath="$home/arch/test/*.jpg" ## path to JPEG images for deletion
testpath="$home/arch/test/" ## path to test directory
spath="$home/arch/test/image_%03d.jpg"  ## source files for video
now=$(date +%Y%m%d) ## current date
apath="$home"/video/"$now".mp4 ## name of today's video file
mfslocation="$home"/arch/test/image_%03d.jpg
fslocation="$home"/arch/test/kamvideo.mp4


gst-launch-1.0 \
    -e multifilesrc location="$mfslocation" \
    ! image/jpeg, framerate=10/1 \
    ! decodebin ! queue ! videoscale \
    ! video/x-raw, width=640, height=480 \
    ! progressreport name=progress \
    ! omxh264enc target-bitrate=1200000 control-rate=variable \
    ! video/x-h264,profile=high\
    ! h264parse \
    ! mp4mux \
    ! filesink location="$fslocation"
```

The files look like this:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 241527 Oct  6 04:12 image_000.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 238558 Oct  6 04:16 image_001.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 238489 Oct  6 04:20 image_002.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 239035 Oct  6 04:24 image_003.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 240861 Oct  6 04:28 image_004.jpg
…
```

This has been working fine for several years, but it recently came to my attention that the first frame in the video is not the first JPEG in the sequence. Normally you would not notice this, except that under Apple's new OS releases (High Sierra and iOS 11) the video will not play because the timestamp of the first frame is after the timestamp of the second frame.

The video plays fine in VLC and under OS versions prior to the current ones.

The first frame of the video seems to be chosen at random from the set of JPEG files.

Sample video is here: [kamvideo.mp4](http://www.mgnewman.com/kamvideo.mp4)

How do I fix this?

Comment: What is `$mfslocation` set to and how do the input file names look like?

Comment: I've added to the original post the information asked for by Floria.

Comment: What happens if you have more than 999 frames? Anyway, I think these are two separate issues - a) the the first frame being wrong and b) the video not playing. A wrong inserted frame should not result in weird timestamps as just the input was just not done correctly - it is a syntactic correct input. Perhaps try to disable B-frames and see if it plays.

Comment: There are never more than 999 frames. I grab one JPEG image every four minutes and encode a video once every 24 hours.

Comment: How do I disable B-frames? (And, what are they?) 

It’s not really that the video doesn’t play. It’s that it doesn’t appear to play until the playback reaches a frame with a time stamp grater than that of the first frame.

Comment: If you look at the video you will see that the first frame was taken just after midnight on day two. Frame 2 was taken at about 4:00 AM on day one. If you play the video it displays frame one until it reaches a frame just after the time stamp of frame one.

Comment: I think the MP4 is broken. MP4Box reports an error and the first sample entry seems not okay. Try `MP4Box -raw 1 kamvideo.mp4` and then `MP4Box -add kamvideo_track1.h264 kamvideo_fixed.mp4` and see if that one behaves better. Probably all files are corrupt but only recent versions of Apple software trip over this one. What GStreamer version is being used?

Comment: Yes. You're right. Only recent versions of Apple software fail. The cause of the failure is the out-of-sequence JPEG in frame #1. Apple software only started choking on this with High Sierra and iOS 11. I know how to manually fix the problem, but I need to figure out why GStreamer (1.4.4) is corrupting the file by putting an out-of-sequence JPEG in frame #1.

Comment: It is not out of order, the MP4 sample entry is just broken (maybe Apple chokes here displaying a wrong frame). Probably the MP4 Muxer or H264 parser is to blame. Try upgrading GStreamer. Version 1.4 is quite old. Recent stable version currently is 1.12.

Comment: pi@rasp ~ $ sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
gstreamer1.0-tools is already the newest version.

Comment: I've given up on this. I've offloaded the video creation task to ffmpeg on a Mac. — It just works….